# TDengine jdbc timezone

Tags: database, jdbc

I used the code below to create timezone reconfigured connection.

```
        operties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(TSDBDriver.PROPERTY_KEY_TIME_ZONE, "UTC+8");
        Connection connDefault = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:TAOS://" + host + ":0/", properties);
```

and then I used the connDefault to create a statement,the use this statement to insert and select data.

```
insert into meters values('2021-07-29 00:00:00', 'taosdata');
select * from meters ;
```

But the java code query result is

> ts=2021-07-29 16:00:00.0

there are 16 hours interval. While I expect the query result is the same as the insert time '2021-07-29 00:00:00'.
what's more the time stored in db is like this

> ```
>    ts       |              name
> ```
>
> 1627545600000 | taosdata

Query OK, 1 row(s) in set (0.008616s)

could someone help figure out why?
In addition, i found on the official website of tdengine always set timezone to "utc-8" does anyone know where that timezone is?

```
  Properties connProps = new Properties();
  connProps.setProperty(TSDBDriver.PROPERTY_KEY_CHARSET, "UTF-8");
  connProps.setProperty(TSDBDriver.PROPERTY_KEY_LOCALE, "en_US.UTF-8");
  connProps.setProperty(TSDBDriver.PROPERTY_KEY_TIME_ZONE, "UTC-8");
  Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, connProps);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like other database software, for example, PostgreSQL, TDengine uses Posix timezone spec which means the offset is opposite with the ISO 8601 standard.